# How to bind AJAX method's result value with html.?

Tags: ajax

### AJAX method

---

Now , I want the count variable to bind with html and need help as i don't have enough knowledge of AJAX

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var token = localStorage.getItem('ngStorage-premier_agent_token')
        var value = 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(token)
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', value);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/activity/listcount",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        var count=data.count;
    }
});
```

Comment: Their is plenty of tutorial on how to perfom an Ajax request , i am afraid this is not the right place to ask people for home work

Comment: I just dont know how to bind it with html and if would have knowledge of it then must have shared with the needy instead.

Comment: when you said bind it to the html you mean  show it on a html ?

Comment: yes and did it this way:   $("#val").html(data.count);

Answer (score 0):

added a container where you want to print your HTML, like a div

```
<div></div>
```

and then append the result to that div on your `success` function

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/activity/listcount",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        $("div").append("result is" + data.count);

    }
});
```